# How to develop a swappable ERC20 token?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap

I am developing a BEP20 token. The employer wants this token to be swappable in PancakeSwap.

When I read source of similar tokens, they add `IUniswapV2Pair`, `IUniswapV2Router01` and `IUniswapV2Router02` interfaces, but I can't find a guide that shows how to use these interfaces in the token contract source.

Is it necessary to use these interfaces for swappable tokens?

If yes, how can we use these interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any token that complies the following criteria is swappable in PancakeSwap:

1. It implements the [ERC-20](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20) ([BEP-20 in Binance ecosystem](https://academy.binance.com/en/glossary/bep-20)).
2. The Smart Contract of the token is deployed in Binance Smart Chain (BSC).

> Is it necessary to use these interfaces for swappable tokens?

Absolutely not (considering what I said above).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any need to have a custom logic in your ERC-20 (or BEP-20, or their analogues for other chain) to support trading in decentralized exchanges. The exchange code is written in a way that ensures any token that implements the ERC-20 interface can be swapped, as long as the implementation does not break some simple invariants. On Uniswap v2 and it's clones, almost all existing ERC-20 tokens can be traded; Uniswap v3 and its clones are more demanding and do not support fee-on-transfer and rebasing tokens, for instance.

The reason developers put `IUniswapV2Pair` or `IUniswapV2Router` addresses in their contract logic is to exempt these addresses from transfer fees, or to have other custom logic, typically related to automatically selling the tokens collected via the transfer fee.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know some documents about using these interface?

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji you have useful links about that in my answer, if helps. https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc20#IERC20

Comment: I understood your answer, but now I want to know how to use `IUniswapV2Pair` and `IUniswapV2Router` interfaces in my token source to decrease transfer fees. Do you know links about this?

Comment: @AlirezaZojaji questions asking for links to external sites aren't typically permitted on Stack Exchange. That said, I'm not aware of much formal documentation on these practices. I'd just go to Etherscan and read a few contracts for popular ERC-20 tokens with transfer fees.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement ERC20 and the factory / router contract do the rest.